# UITablewViewController showing black screen

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have searched StackOverflow for this, and there was not an answer that helped me.

I have a UITablewViewController  with this code :

```
class MessagesViewController: UITableViewController
{

    lazy var activeChats = [PrivateChatUITableViewCell]()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)


    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return activeChats.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = UITableViewCell( style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "chat_room_cell" ) as! PrivateChatUITableViewCell
        let currentUserID = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.uid
        let query = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(currentUserID!)

        _ = query.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in

            if  let data        = snapshot.value as? [String: String],
                let contactName        = data["userName"],
                let newMsgs        = data["newMessage"],
                let contactImg = data["userImageStr"]
            {
                let contactID = snapshot.key

                //cell.ContactImageView = UIImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(contactImg)
                cell.ContactName.text = contactName
                cell.NewNotificationsNum.text = newMsgs
                cell.ContactID = contactID
            }
        })



        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        chatToLoad = activeChats[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_chatroom", sender: self)
    }

    var chatToLoad: PrivateChatUITableViewCell? = nil

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "segue_to_chatroom")
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! PrivateChatViewController
            destination.senderId = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.uid
            destination.senderDisplayName = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.displayName
            destination.contactID = chatToLoad!.ContactID

        }
    }

}
```

That is located in a `TabViewController`. When I click that tab, the view is all BLACK. I tried setting it to white by using `self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` (As you can see in the ViewDidLoad method) but that did not help. I tried to manually set the color to white and then default, but that did not help either.

The TabBar is connected to a `NavigationController` which presents the `UIView` modally.

A picture of my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard snapshot]

[image: The Black Screen]

How do I make the background color white ?

Comment: Does it show the navigation bar? If it doesn't, maybe there is a problem with your segue

Comment: Please make sure that your storyboard has initial view controller is set., because looking into source code that it should crash on  `self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)`

Comment: I just updated my post, added the black screen.

Comment: @Glaphi Navigation bar is shown, as can be seen in the picture I just added :)

Comment: @deoKasuhal I don't understand what you're saying. This is not my initial VC, and I do have one set.